# How come a string of a musical instrument produces sound when it looks like a transverse wave instead of a longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves, acoustics

As you may probably tell, I am still new to physics and in school, we're learning about waves right now. When I watched how strings vibrate, they looked like transverse wave.

So, my initial thought was all waves looked like transverse wave. But then, after learning the chapter about waves, I found out that sound is actually longitudinal wave. Or is it all the time?

How come strings vibrate like transverse wave but still produce sound?

Comment: A transversely vibrating drumhead can push the air unleashing longitudinal compression waves in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In string instruments, the [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(instrument)) will transfer the transverse motion of the string to a soundboard. This then moves to put the air above and below it in motion, causing a longitudinal wave.

The soundboard is also often part of a resonance cavity. For example, the body of an [acoustic guitar](http://acoustic%20guitar) is a Helmholtz resonator, where much of the sound comes from air moving in and out through the hole.

Comment: So does that mean when the energy is transferred through the solid, it is in transverse motion, but when the energy goes to gas, it changes to longitudinal wave?

Comment: @AmmarSarif Terms like "transverse" and "longitudinal" are relative to the direction of propagation of the wave. But there is not really a wave in the soundboard or in the Helmholtz resonator. Or in a loudspeaker..